# datetime and formatting - python

Tags: python, datetime, time, formatting

i am trying to print out the current hours mins seconds and milliseconds to a file accurately but cant seem to find the right formatting for the date format

```
log_file.write(datetime.datetime.strptime(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}","%H-%M-%S-%f"))
```

I'm using this and want it to output as time from when python file was opened like:

0:0:5:123
h:m:s:ms

Comment: You need to use `strftime` (datetime to string), not `strptime` (string to datetime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the current time using `datetime.datetime.now()`, format it in the following format: `%H:%M:%S:%f` (H represents hours, M represents minutes, S represents seconds and f represents microseconds).
After that, we format the date by stripping the last 3 digits of the microseconds (f) with `formatted_time = current_datetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f")[:-3]`.
Next, we open the chosen log file using a context manager with `with open("log.txt", "w") as log_file:`.
Inside the `with` block, we write the date formatted to the log file with `log_file.write(formatted_time)`.
The `with` context manager will ensure that the file is automatically closed at the end of the block, making the use of `log_file.close()` unnecessary.

**note: you must open the file using the appropriate mode ('w' for write mode)**

this is the code

```
import datetime

# Open the file using the context manager
with open("log.txt", "w") as log_file:
    # Get the current datetime
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Format the datetime as h:m:s:ms in the American format
    formatted_time = current_datetime.strftime("%I:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]

    # Write the formatted time to the log file
    log_file.write(formatted_time)

# The file will be automatically closed when exiting the 'with' block
```

this is output

```
13:40:15:063
```

H=13:M=40:S=15:F=063

**Note:**

- %H%M%S%f is 24 hour format
- %I%M%S%f is 12h formatù

Comment: FYI if you use `open`'s context manager you can avoid to explicitly `log_file.close()`: it's generally a good practice [example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/with-open-in-python-with-statement-syntax-example/)

Comment: Hi you are absolutely right! Using the open context manager with the with statement is a really good practice and can help you avoid the need to explicitly close the file. Thanks for the feedback I will modify the code using the with

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert `datetime` to a string, you can use `strftime` function with the datetime object.

Code:

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S-%f"))
```

Output:

```
19-04-37-298200
```

Answer (score 0):

The strftime() function should work. See the code below for an example.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
formatted_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f")

print(formatted_now)
```